# I applied an inception model and my model has been savde but how do I avoid training the dataset again and agian?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision

I have same my inception model in Pycharm using TensorFlow library. Every time I run the project, it starts training the Data set. I want to skip the training every time I run model because once the model has been save ,there is no need to train the data again and again. How I get to know my model has been save successfully? How can I apply the save model in same file?

Comment: falak if my answer solve your problem, please accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You can save/restore/load your model using TensorFlow:

Save:

```
builder = tf.saved_model.builder.SavedModelBuilder(export_dir) with tf.Session(graph=tf.Graph()) as sess:   ...   builder.add_meta_graph_and_variables(sess,
                                           [tag_constants.TRAINING],
                                           signature_def_map=foo_signatures,
                                           assets_collection=foo_assets,
                                           strip_default_attrs=True)
...
builder.save()
```

Load:

```
with tf.Session(graph=tf.Graph()) as sess:
  tf.saved_model.loader.load(sess, [tag_constants.TRAINING], export_dir)
  ...
```

For further reference: [TensorFlow Guide on Saving a Model](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model)

Answer (score -1):

Actually, once you have saved your model, some files will be saved to your directory with the extension .YAML, .h5 or .meta(for graph), you can check the accuracy of model by restoring from saved file, just for sanity check.

There is nice tutorial on this:

1. https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model
2. http://cv-tricks.com/tensorflow-tutorial/save-restore-tensorflow-models-quick-complete-tutorial/

If you are use keras-api to build model, then this link will be useful for saving and restoring https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-save-a-keras-model